# Can I provide bank statements from multiple accounts when applying for a New Zealand visa?

Tags: visas, money, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, new-zealand

I have multiple accounts under different banks for different purposes, which should I present?

Does the visa officer want to check if I have enough money in my savings maintained consistently over a period or to see my day to day expenses and transactions showing flight/accommodation bookings?

My accounts are:

Bank 1 - Payroll Account

Where my salary is deposited. I transfer some money every month to another bank account for saving purposes, and into another bank account for everyday transactions. I saved some balance in this account too and rarely shows funds being transferred out because i use this only to save.

Bank 2 - Saving account

This account only used for savings. I always transfer some of my salary here every payday. It shows funds transferred in and rarely shows funds being transferred out because i only use this to save my money

Bank 3 - Everyday transactions

I transfer money here from Savings for my daily expenses such as foods, consumtive purposes and any cash withdrawals. I do not keep any balance in this account because i used this purely for consumption.

In addition to my bank accounts, i also have stock investments which my portfolio and account statements are being sent to my personal email each month.

I feel as I should present every single bank accounts to show the full picture of my expenses and i would also wanted to present my stock investments portfolio.

I plan to explain the movement in my cover letter. But i feel like i should mark the movement such as funds transfer between accounts with different colored markers for each movement type (such as salary payments, savings, transfers, etc.) but i am concerned if the visa officers would get confused and reject my application.

Would the officers reject it stating they can't determine how money got into it?

Would it be better if i transfer all my savings to one of my accounts?

Any help and advises would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When I presented my supporting documents on my finances in my cover letter for my recent UK visitor visa application, what I did was to mention first my letter of appointment, which shows my stipend, followed by my pay slips, which show my savings account account number, and then the printout on my savings account where I put notes to pinpoint my stipend in local currency and for which month. By doing this, the entry clearance officer could easily connect my sources of funds and where the funds are going.

Comment: I recommend you to not do any large transfers (even from one account to another, both of which you own) as a Border officer will almost assuredly suspect you of some sort of funds parking or other temporary transfers of funds from elsewhere. The best thing is to show accounts with long histories of transactions, explainable (by pay slips, etc) which are yours.

Comment: Your question is long, but still very generic. If you have stocks, probably you have enough funds, just show some accounts which proof your funds, and your income. Less funds, the more detailed you should give, and this is the most frequent question in this site, so your question title is correct but it may be misleading (to many of our readers). Remember: funds is only one things they *may* look. Good job/income (with future) is more important (so your payroll account, and some account with funds).

Comment: Not only can you provide statements from multiple banks, but in many cases you have to: if you moved large amounts from one account to another, only providing all those statements will enable the officer reviewing your application to understand it all. However, it also complicated things and can easily lead to interpretation errors on their part, so providing simple and clear explanations of the movements in your cover letter may help.